# HDD Disappears on Ubuntu 22.04 Until System Reboot

Tags: mount, hard-drive, suspend, disk

Every now and then, after I bring my PC up from the suspended mode, my HDD gets "lost". I am unable to access any directories on it. Nor does it show up when I run any of the following `lsblk`, `parted -l`, `blkid`, `fdisk -l`. Rebooting the system brings it back every single time. Running `mount -a` does not work. Any help on troubleshooting this is appreciated.

**Edit:**

The drive is a non-system HDD, which has the following entry in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=ec6eedab-0afa-4875-af56-e9a1e3fcf85f                       /media/user/Storage                       auto    nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show                 0       0
```

Comment: Add information on the type of drive: internal? USB drive? Is it included in `/etc/fstab` or does it automount? Beware that suspending does not always work 100%, and this can be one of the issues.

Comment: @vanadium Added the info. Could you explain the suspending not working 100%?